# Same CGI works from one directory but not from another (Apache2 on Ubuntu)

Tags: apache2, cgi

I don't need redirecting or what-not, just a strict plain copy -- a second directory that works 100% the same as the first one (I need it say as a starting point for a new project).

I did the following (names are slightly different, below I use "a" and "b"):

a) under /var/www :

> sudo rsync -rpuva a/ b

b) under /etc/apache2/sites-available:

> sudo cp -p a b

c) edited "b" so that "diff a b" gives me:

```
:: &#60;Directory &#47;var&#47;www&#47;a&#47;
:: &#62;Directory &#47;var&#47;www&#47;b&#47;
```

(*Sorry but I cannot quite figure out how to properly escape LT(<), GT(>)  and SLASH(/) above. When I made it look OK, SO complained saying "your code is not formatted properly" (and where is code?!?!)* ).

d) restarted apache

However when I open in browser my-site/a/script.cgi it welcomes me with a hello message while my-site/b/script.cgi gives me the content of it

The script.cgi is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

print "Content-type: text/html"
print ""
print "<h1>Hello from Python!</h1>"
```

---

There are no errors in the log.

I run Linux
#29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:19:42 UTC 2013 
and Apache

Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Mar 15 2013 14:04:36

I don't see how this can be possible.
Please help!

Note: I restart using both apachectl and apache2ctl : maybe that is the problem?

Comment: I think you have accidently wrote the wrong &#60; and &#62; . You probably meant that the diff looks like this: `<Directory /var/www/a>` and `<Directory /var/www/b>` ? What is "::" in front of each line? I never saw that in an Apache configuration file.

Comment: Just to be sure, did you use `apache2ctl -k restart`? Is it possible that any other configuration file, maybe a global one, accidently permitted CGI-execution only for the /var/www/a directory? You can do a recursive search using `grep -r "<your search term>" /etc/apache2/` . Also verify using `ls -l /var/www/b/` that all *.cgi files have the execution flag +x set for the world-user (left column).

Comment: Thanks rinntech. Yes I wrote &#60; etc. because I couldn't format the output using the markdown as I wanted. It was supposed to look exactly like you posted: "a" vs. "b", nothing else is different in two config files.

Comment: Yes I did 'apache2ctl -k restart'. Nothing's changed. No, /var/www/a is never mentioned anywhere except in its config file (which is "a" under /etc/apache2/sites-available/). Actually I forgot to mention that I also have sym. links from /etc/apache2/sites-available/ to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/ (both for "a" and for "b").

Comment: As for the UNIX mode ("execution flag +x set") : yes everything is exactly the same under a/ and under b/ (I used rsync to create b from a, see my orig. post). But thank you very much anyway! :-)

Comment: to be 100% sure,  please set following `<Directory /var/www> Options +ExecCGI AddHandler cgi-script .py</Directory>` . newline in front of AddHandler of course. That are 4 lines.  I think somehow the ExecCGI flag is not set correctly.  Please also check the symlinks.  Apache will only look into sites-enabled/ . ( sites-available/ has only the purpose of holding all your configs so you can symlink all active pages to sites-enabled/ )

Answer (score 1):

Enable your new site "sudo a2ensite b" and restart apache